# Blue-collar / Foreman / Project Management Vernacular

Tags: preparation

I'm going to be installing something over and over again in many homes, and in order to help me keep track of what I need to do the job, I'm creating two parts lists for the three-hundred or so different items that I need.

One list is for items that will be used over and over again on different homes (such as my power tools), and the other for items that will be consumed by the project (such as, for example, the two pumps that are installed with each system.)

The names for these lists that I've come up with are "Persistent Items" and "Consumed Items", but obviously, while those names convey the idea, they sound rather stupid.  "Perennial" or "recurring" could be used instead of "persistent," but I'm on the fence about the whole thing until I can get some feedback.

So my question is this -- does anybody here have names for these lists that are better than "persistent" and "consumed"?

Comment: This question might fit better on [English Language & Usage](http://english.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I often make checklists for jobs, especially if they are a distance from my shop, and assures my helpers get all the stuff I want on the site.  Rather than one word headings, I usually two or three checklists like 1) Tools and equipment. This includes the obvious tools and things like ladders, extension cords, compressor hoses and the like. 2) Material list. this has all the components that will be needed and purchased by the customer. Lumber, trim, paint, light fixtures, insulation etc. 3) Shop stock. this list contains all the consumable items that are not billed individually. This includes stick nails, small electrical supplies, fasteners, tapes, caulking etc. I build these lists when I am estimating the job, then  keep these lists in a customer file, so it is easy to bill out materials etc when the job is done.

Comment: I'm going to go with (1) Equipment, (2) Materials [stuff that is not typically consumed completely in one job, such as my 100-piece packs of stainless washers], and (3) Parts [parts that are consumed entirely by each job].

Thanks, guys.

Answer (score 1):

"Capital" vs. "Consumables" or "Supplies" or "Parts"